# Cannot normally boot Tails from USB on Clevo N857EK1

Tags: live-usb

I cant normally boot Tails on my laptop.It start freezing when I press button Start (See photo) or when choosing Wi-Fi. Please see my Bios setting.I try with different settings but it doesnt help.Also the same situation when I try other USB ports,other USB drive.Also I write image to USB drive with UltraIso and Etcher (the same situation with both programs).I think problem is in BIOS.Please help me.

P.S.I have installed Linux from USB(but I think I was lucky because sometimes it also freeze)

Photos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxlDc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can boot with this usb in other PC, then you can know if is the software/usb or the BIOS.
And if there are some more options in your BIOS like 'safe boot' disable it, it is intended to only allow to boot from 'known' images (windows)
But really, try to see if you can boot with this USB somewhere else, then you know is the usb port or the BIOs config in your PC

Comment: safe boot is disabled , I try with it - the same.

Comment: I cant check Usb drive on other device but as I try 2 USB drives with different ports I can say that problem is not in USB port,drive